# Чтение GZIP ответа на SOAP запрос

Tags: java, soap, gzip

Я отправляю через SOAP post-запрос имеющий следующие свойства

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

В ответ приходит

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Я пытался сделать так

```java
URL url = new URL(addr);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("...... указываю все свойства, в них проблем нет
connection.setDoOutput(true);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
pw.write(request);
pw.flush();

connection.connect();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String output;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(output);
}
in.close();
```

Ожидаемо что это не работает, ответ на это приходит вот такой

```
�iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'��
```

Ну и ответ приходит как xml в xml

[image]

B у эти xml похоже разная кодировка.

Как правильно принять ответ ?

Comment: Вероятно, Вам сюда https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

Comment: Используйте класс `GZIPInputStream`

Comment: А Transfer-Encoding случаем не chunked, а то часто с gzip в комплекте идет ... Лучше поискать какое нибудь более высокоуровневое средство отправки запросов, что бы само ответ декодировало

Comment: [Первая же выдача](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-HttpUrlConnection-with-GZIP-encoding.html) в запросе гуглу "httpurlconnection gzip encoding java"

Comment: @pak-uula спасибо, я долго гуглил, но видимо не правильно формировал вопрос)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно разжать ответ:

```java
Reader reader = null;
if ("gzip".equals(connection.getContentEncoding())) {
   reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream()));
} else {
   reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
}
```

И дальше будто никакого сжатия нет.

Answer (score 1):

Последующую проблему с парсингом вложенного CDATA xml решил. 
Привожу полный код

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String addr = "https://....123";
    String request = "<soapenv:Authorization>\n" +
            "   123213213213\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    URL url = new URL(addr);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(request.length()));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://урл/Authorization");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "урл");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    // Write XML
    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    byte[] b = request.getBytes("UTF-8");
    outputStream.write(b);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    Reader reader = null;
    if ("gzip".equals(connection.getContentEncoding())) {
        reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream()));
    } else {
        reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
    }

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while (true) {
        int ch = reader.read();
        if (ch == -1) {
            break;
        }
        response.append((char) ch);
    }

    System.out.println(response);

    Document doc = getXMLFromString(response.toString());
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:Response");
    Element line = (Element) nodes.item(0);
    System.out.println(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));


}

public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        return cd.getData();
    }
    return "?";
}

public static Document getXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    return doc;
}
```